# JQuery vs Same origin policy

Tags: jquery, ads, same-origin-policy

I am using an ad content provider on my site which I really love for the simplicity of implementation, however sometimes their ads play annoying video and audio even though they promise they block that stuff -_-.

I tried to write a recursive javascript/JQuery function to drill down into the IFrames and find and disable any flash video objects, but I eventually learned of the complexities of the "Same Origin Policy" which won't let me drill into any IFrames that aren't part of my own site.  I also thought of pulling in the HTML from the ad and running it through my server for validation, but 1. the ad rotates just about every time you hit the page 2. I don't think it would count if I displayed the HTML from the ad without going through the content provider's site correctly and 3. I don't want that overhead on my server in the first place.

I have sent an e-mail to the customer service department of the ad content provider, but I would like to be able to take this fix into my own hands if necessary.  Is there anything that I can do to stop this that doesn't involve me blocking half my revenue producing ads trying to figure out which one(s) have the videos?

Answer (score 3):

You could possibly try to proxy the load of the ads. But really, anything you do to monkey with the ads would probably be against the terms of service of the ad company. (Think of it from their end: would they want to be giving you money knowing you were messing with their ads?)

Most ad vendors do offer some level of customization (so that, for example, competitors' ads don't show up on your site) so that is probably what you should pursue. Either that or get a different ad provider.

Comment: The ad vendor's customization includes a little checkbox that says "Allow video ads to automatically play audio".  It doesn't work obviously.  I have also toyed with the notion of getting a different ad provider in the past as well, but this one is just so simple and i like just about everything else about them.  You may be right though.

Comment: Honestly I wish there was another way. :(

Comment: It makes me a little mad that I am supposed to be at the mercy of the advertisers even though I am the one that puts all of the work into the site that will draw the viewers in.  Most of my advertisers are good.  But there are a few bad apples out there that ruin my profits and hard work by annoying my visitors and regulars so that they aren't likely to come back or are likely to come back with ad-block plus.

Comment: Yeah that's why most ad networks allow you to block certain advertisers. Sure there's no way in their control panels to do such? This is a pretty common thing after all...

Comment: Yes, I can block individual ads, there is a huge list of the hundred of ad campaigns that qualify for each of my ad zones, but if I checked each and every one of them individually (and I have before), not one of them will play a video, and I have determined that this is because my ad content provider allows users to submit ads from other ad content providers in a rotating block (its recursive advertising if you will), and these kinds of ads just happen to have some of the highest CPM values so I would prefer not to block them completely, and i'm not 100% certain which ones the offenders are.

Comment: Damn. Well usually you can block advertisers by name to block all their ads. But not with your network?

Comment: well there is a search and I could just check all their checkboxes and block them all, but like I said, the actual offenders are in a rotating block (50+ ads in just 1 advertisement slot that rotate) so their names wouldn't show up in a search as the blocks don't list their inner ads.